# MySQL Query Using IN Statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get the following query to run and I know I have just not formatted it correctly. Yet I can not figure out what is wrong.

```
WHERE P1 = $num_P1 AND P2 IN ($num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_P6) AND P1 = $num_P1 AND P3 IN ($num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_P6)
```

If someone can help it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it to use IN statement in this way :

```
$array1 = array($num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_P6);
$array1_string = implode(",", $array1);
```

use like this :

```
P2 IN ($array1_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE P1 = $num_P1 AND (P2 IN ($num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_P6)
                    OR  P3 IN ($num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_P6)
)
```

Comment: Perhaps some clarification to how this answer differs from the OP's attempt would be helpful.  (It looks fairly subtle as it is parenthesis based.)

Comment: Yes subtle parentheses are the key ;-)